# Create a list dynamically using json array as an input

Tags: jquery

I want to know how to produce the HTML list dynamically using the json array of objects as input.

```js
{title: "Title1", param: "param1"},
{title: "Title2", param: "param2"},
{title: "Title3", param: "param3"}
```

```html
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li>
    <a href="#mypage" onclick="myfunc(param1);">Title1</a>
  </li>
<li>
    <a href="#mypage" onclick="myfunc(param2);">Title2</a>
  </li>
<li>
    <a href="#mypage" onclick="myfunc(param3);">Title3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you know how to loop through your JSON data?

Comment: angularjs is usually really great for doing things like this. I'd recommend you try it!

Comment: yes, I know how to iterate over json data. It is more how to write jquery code for a simple list and then for a list with childs. The childs will be specified in the json array as well.

Comment: @Lafani you really should have specified the above in your question. It's more complex than the simple answer I gave you based on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var json = [
    {"title": "Title1", "param": "param1", "subMenu": [
        {"title": "SubTitle1", "param": "param1-1"},
        {"title": "SubTitle2", "param": "param1-2", "subMenu": [
            {"title": "SubSubTitle1", "param": "param1-1-1"},
            {"title": "SubSubTitle2", "param": "param1-1-2"},
            {"title": "SubSubTitle2", "param": "param1-1-3"}
        ]}
    ]},
    {"title": "Title2", "param": "param2"},
    {"title": "Title3", "param": "param3"}
];

var myfunc = function(param) {
    alert(param);
};

function makeList(array, root){
    if(typeof root === 'undefined'){
        root = $('body');
    }
    var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
    root.append(ul);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var li = $("<li></li>");
        ul.append(li);
        var a = $("<a href='#' data-param='" + array[i].param + "'>" + array[i].title + "</a>");
        li.append(a);
        a.click(function() {
            alert($(this).data("param"));
        });

        if(typeof array[i].subMenu !== 'undefined'){
             makeList(array[i].subMenu, li);
        }
    }
}
makeList(json);
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqv33t82/2/)

You just loop through the json array and put the property values where you want, then use recursion to deal with nested lists. I put the param in a data attr to make things a bit simpler.

Comment: Thanks much. My actual problem is a bit more complex :(. Each title can have a sub-title and each sub-title can have a sub-sub-title as well.

Comment: **Whala!** Recursion! See edit. (fiddle link is updated as well)

Comment: here is the quirk...the list shows the bullets beside them whereas my static html that uses jquery's listview with collapsible property does not show bullets. Also, the top level menu item does not have any link associated with it as per jquery's listview definition. I thought that I'll be able to fix it but doesn't seem to have any luck so far :(

Comment: I figured it out...just need to add the root.trigger('create').

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery [**$.each**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through an array of data.

```
var data = [
    {title: "Title1", param: "param1"},
    {title: "Title2", param: "param2"},
    {title: "Title3", param: "param3"}
];
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    var html = '<li><a href="#mypage" onclick="myfunc('+value.param+');">'+value.title+'</a></li>';
    $('ul').append(html); // ul could also be a class of the list
});
```

This would be a raw jQuery solution. (not tested)  It also uses your onClick handler.